# On two different size planets occurs radioactive decay, is the amount of decay the same?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, particle-physics

Imagine there is a planet as big as our sun and a earth like planet. On both planets is a box with equal amounts of radioactive polonium. In between the planets is a measure station. After 10 years the planets communicate to the station how much of the polonium is decayed.

Is the amount of decayed polonium on the big planet more, less or the same as on the small planet?

Comment: In regards to the 10 year time frame, is that 10 years in the measure station reference frame or does each planet wait 10 years in their own reference frame?

Comment: in the measure station

Comment: I feel like just from gravitational time dilation, the larger planet would have fewer decays as there is more gravity so time in it's reference frame would go slower. At least that from my limited understanding of the theory.

Answer (score 0):

If the gravitational field strength of the big planet is larger than the one on the small planet (and you have no additional relativistic effects) you would expect from General Relativity (Equivalence Principle) that you have a gravitational time dilation on the big planet. Thus the half-life of radioactive plutonium should be a little bit larger on the big planet. Thus less radioactive plutonium decays should have happened in the box on the big planet giving you less decayed plutonium there.

Comment: Would your answer be different if the planets had equal mass but different speed?

Comment: This answer is tempting but (v1) incorrect.  Time dilation (both from gravitational curvature and from and linear motion) affects all processes equally.  In order to determine the decay rate precisely, experimenters on both planets would have to construct a time reference, e.g. a [cesium fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock).  Since the clock frequency and the decay rate are affected the same way by time dilation, their ratio would be the same on both planets. Instead, observers on the two planets would disagree about when ten years have elapsed.

Comment: If you interested in a quick review of a number of relativistic effect in connection with gravitational time dilation, I recommend the Wikipedia article  "Gravitational Time Dilation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation .

Comment: In any case for an outside observer, the effect of gravitational time dilation on radioactive decay is analogous to the (on earth) astronomically observed gravitational redshift in spectral lines from stars (e.g. white dwarfs)  with strong gravitational fields.

Comment: Rob, the measurement station just read both decays of the planets at the same time, does this station still measure equal decays?

Comment: @Marijn An outside measurement station would see different counts of decay events, but the issue there is time dilation.  There's more interesting question about whether gravitational fields affect *intrinsic* decay rates, the way that being surrounded by energetic electrons can change the effective lifteime of a positron-emitting nucleus or the way that passing through Earth changes neutrino oscillation times.  I think there's no evidence for such a gravitationally induced change, but I doubt it's strongly constrained either.

Comment: Do you mean with intrinsic the same as happens with cesium atomic clocks flying around the earth or was this also only due to relativty?

Comment: @rob - so an outside observer of the two plutonium boxes on the two planets would see different times until half of the plutonium  have decayed on different planets ! According to GR the physical laws should be the same at all locations. So the observers on the planets measure the same half lives. There is absolutely no reason to think that the *intrinsic* half lives would be  different when the same physical conditions are upheld on the planets. You can change  electron capture decay rates by offering more electrons to the nucleus to be captured. This is, however, a change in the experiment.

Comment: @freecharly Yes, exactly.  The way that I interpreted Marijn's original question was whether simply moving from a low-gravity to high-gravity region of space corresponds to this sort of "change of experiment"; I suspect the answer is no, but I'm pretty sure there's not any carefully-considered experimental evidence to support that.